# Give basic boto create_qualification_type example

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, mechanicalturk

Can anyone give a basic example on how to use boto's mturk create_qualification_type? Please include an example of a valid answer_key_xml.

Or please point to some documentation with examples. The official [documentation](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/mturk.html) is not very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: you should include what you are trying at the moment, or a cut down version of it that shows it not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a Qualification test Question (it was created to vet basic programming/code-reading skills):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<QuestionForm xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2005-10-01/QuestionForm.xsd">
    <Overview>
        <Title>Trivia Test Qualification</Title>
    </Overview>
    <Question>
        <QuestionIdentifier>question1</QuestionIdentifier>
        <QuestionContent>
            <Text>The following code will allow the program to obtain a name from the keyboard:</Text>
            <Text>String name = Console.readLine("Enter name"):</Text>
        </QuestionContent>
        <AnswerSpecification>
            <SelectionAnswer>
              <StyleSuggestion>radiobutton</StyleSuggestion>
              <Selections>
                <Selection>
                  <SelectionIdentifier>true</SelectionIdentifier>
                  <Text>True</Text>
                </Selection>
                <Selection>
                  <SelectionIdentifier>false</SelectionIdentifier>
                  <Text>False</Text>
                </Selection>
              </Selections>  
            </SelectionAnswer>  
        </AnswerSpecification>
    </Question>
    <Question>
        <QuestionIdentifier>question2</QuestionIdentifier>
        <QuestionContent>
            <Text>The method length( ) will return an integer which represents the length of a string value.</Text>
        </QuestionContent>
        <AnswerSpecification>
            <SelectionAnswer>
              <StyleSuggestion>radiobutton</StyleSuggestion>
              <Selections>
                <Selection>
                  <SelectionIdentifier>true</SelectionIdentifier>
                  <Text>True</Text>
                </Selection>
                <Selection>
                  <SelectionIdentifier>false</SelectionIdentifier>
                  <Text>False</Text>
                </Selection>
              </Selections>  
            </SelectionAnswer>  
        </AnswerSpecification>
    </Question>
    <Question>
        <QuestionIdentifier>question3</QuestionIdentifier>
        <QuestionContent>
            <Text>The name of a variable is known as its:</Text>
        </QuestionContent>
        <AnswerSpecification>
            <SelectionAnswer>
              <StyleSuggestion>radiobutton</StyleSuggestion>
              <Selections>
                <Selection>
                  <SelectionIdentifier>1</SelectionIdentifier>
                  <Text>Identifier</Text>
                </Selection>
                <Selection>
                  <SelectionIdentifier>2</SelectionIdentifier>
                  <Text>Constant</Text>
                </Selection>
                <Selection>
                  <SelectionIdentifier>3</SelectionIdentifier>
                  <Text>Data Type</Text>
                </Selection>
                <Selection>
                  <SelectionIdentifier>4</SelectionIdentifier>
                  <Text>Base</Text>
                </Selection>                
              </Selections>  
            </SelectionAnswer>  
        </AnswerSpecification>
    </Question> 
    <Question>
        <QuestionIdentifier>question4</QuestionIdentifier>
        <QuestionContent>
            <Text>All variables must be declared before they can be used?</Text>
        </QuestionContent>
        <AnswerSpecification>
            <SelectionAnswer>
              <StyleSuggestion>radiobutton</StyleSuggestion>
              <Selections>
                <Selection>
                  <SelectionIdentifier>true</SelectionIdentifier>
                  <Text>True</Text>
                </Selection>
                <Selection>
                  <SelectionIdentifier>false</SelectionIdentifier>
                  <Text>False</Text>
                </Selection>
              </Selections>  
            </SelectionAnswer>
        </AnswerSpecification>
    </Question> 
    <Question>
        <QuestionIdentifier>question5</QuestionIdentifier>
        <QuestionContent>
            <Text>Array indexing always starts with the number</Text>
        </QuestionContent>
        <AnswerSpecification>
            <SelectionAnswer>
              <StyleSuggestion>radiobutton</StyleSuggestion>
              <Selections>
                <Selection>
                  <SelectionIdentifier>0</SelectionIdentifier>
                  <Text>0</Text>
                </Selection>
                <Selection>
                  <SelectionIdentifier>1</SelectionIdentifier>
                  <Text>1</Text>
                </Selection>
                <Selection>
                  <SelectionIdentifier>2</SelectionIdentifier>
                  <Text>2</Text>
                </Selection>
                <Selection>
                  <SelectionIdentifier>/0</SelectionIdentifier>
                  <Text>/0</Text>
                </Selection>                                
              </Selections>  
            </SelectionAnswer>
        </AnswerSpecification>
    </Question>             
</QuestionForm>
```

And here is an example of the answer key for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnswerKey xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2005-10-01/AnswerKey.xsd">
    <Question>
        <QuestionIdentifier>question1</QuestionIdentifier>
        <AnswerOption>
          <SelectionIdentifier>true</SelectionIdentifier>
          <AnswerScore>10</AnswerScore>
        </AnswerOption>
    </Question>
    <Question>
        <QuestionIdentifier>question2</QuestionIdentifier>
        <AnswerOption>
          <SelectionIdentifier>true</SelectionIdentifier>
          <AnswerScore>10</AnswerScore>
        </AnswerOption>
    </Question>
    <Question>
        <QuestionIdentifier>question3</QuestionIdentifier>
        <AnswerOption>
          <SelectionIdentifier>1</SelectionIdentifier>
          <AnswerScore>10</AnswerScore>
        </AnswerOption>
    </Question>
    <Question>
        <QuestionIdentifier>question4</QuestionIdentifier>
        <AnswerOption>
          <SelectionIdentifier>true</SelectionIdentifier>
          <AnswerScore>10</AnswerScore>
        </AnswerOption>
    </Question> 
    <Question>
        <QuestionIdentifier>question5</QuestionIdentifier>
        <AnswerOption>
          <SelectionIdentifier>0</SelectionIdentifier>
          <AnswerScore>10</AnswerScore>
        </AnswerOption>
    </Question>     
    <QualificationValueMapping>
        <PercentageMapping>
            <MaximumSummedScore>50</MaximumSummedScore>
        </PercentageMapping>
    </QualificationValueMapping>
</AnswerKey>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that creates a qualification test using boto 2. There should be a way to create an answer key using boto, instead of writing XML, but I have not found it.

```
from boto.mturk.connection import MTurkConnection
from boto.mturk.question import AnswerSpecification, SelectionAnswer
from boto.mturk.question import Question, QuestionContent, QuestionForm
from boto.mturk.question import FormattedContent, Overview

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'PUT YOUR AWS KEY ID HERE'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'PUT YOUR AWS ACCESS KEY HERE'

questions = []
answers = []

# Question 1
questionContent = QuestionContent()
questionContent.append_field('Title', 'What is your favorite meme?')
questionContent.append(
    FormattedContent('<p>Make sure to think this through!</p>')
)
questionAnswer = AnswerSpecification(SelectionAnswer(
    min=1,
    max=1,
    style='radiobutton',
    selections=[
        ('Good Guy Greg', 0),
        ('Scumbag Steve', 1),
        ('Success Kid', 2)
    ],
))
questions.append(Question(
    identifier='q1',
    content=questionContent,
    answer_spec=questionAnswer,
    is_required=True,
))
answers.append("""\
<Question>
    <QuestionIdentifier>q1</QuestionIdentifier>
    <AnswerOption>
        <SelectionIdentifier>2</SelectionIdentifier>
        <AnswerScore>60</AnswerScore>
    </AnswerOption>
</Question> 
""")

# Question 2
questionContent = QuestionContent()
questionContent.append_field(
    'Title',
    'Complete the name of this meme: Socially Awkward ___ ?'
)
questionAnswer = AnswerSpecification(SelectionAnswer(
    min=1,
    max=1,
    style='radiobutton',
    selections=[
        ('Adult', 0),
        ('Penguin', 1),
        ('Doge', 2)
    ],
))
questions.append(Question(
    identifier='q2',
    content=questionContent,
    answer_spec=questionAnswer,
    is_required=True,
))
answers.append("""\
<Question>
    <QuestionIdentifier>q2</QuestionIdentifier>
    <AnswerOption>
        <SelectionIdentifier>1</SelectionIdentifier>
        <AnswerScore>40</AnswerScore>
    </AnswerOption>
</Question> 
""")

# Make the overall question form
testForm = QuestionForm()
overview = Overview()
overview.append_field('Text', 'This test is hard but fair. Try it!')
testForm.append(overview)
for q in questions:
    testForm.append(q)

# Make the answer key XML
answerKey = '<AnswerKey xmlns="%s">\n' % (
    'http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2005-10-01/AnswerKey.xsd'
)
answerKey += ''.join(answers)
answerKey += """\
<QualificationValueMapping>
    <PercentageMapping>
        <MaximumSummedScore>100</MaximumSummedScore>
    </PercentageMapping>
</QualificationValueMapping>
</AnswerKey>
"""

name = 'My Special Qualification'
description = 'My HITS require you to know your memes.'
mtc = MTurkConnection(
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    host='mechanicalturk.sandbox.amazonaws.com',
)
mtc.create_qualification_type(
    name,
    description,
    status='Active',
    keywords=['memes', 'fun'],
    retry_delay=120,
    test=testForm,
    answer_key=answerKey,
    test_duration=3600,
    auto_granted=False,
)
```